# The requested resource () is not available. Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I am getting the following error when I run my web service on tomcat:

```
 HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource () is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
```

here is the code I am getting error:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@WebMethod(operationName = "getTransactionDetails")
public List<MyTransactionWSBean> getTransactionDetails(
    @WebParam(name = "sessionId") long sessionId,
    @WebParam(name = "customerId") long customerId) throws PayboxFault {

MyTransactionWSBean bean = null;
List<MyTransactionWSBean> beanresponse = null;
WSAttribute response = null;
try {
    if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
    LOG.info("Inside updateCustomerRole Service");
    }
    bean = new MyTransactionWSBean();
    WSAttribute wsAttribute = new WSAttribute();
    wsAttribute.setSessionID(sessionId);
    bean.setCustomerId(customerId);
    wsAttribute.setBeanObject(bean);
    wsAttribute.setOperationName("getTransactionDetails");
    IRequestHandler iRequestHandler = HBLUtil
        .getRequestHandler(RequestHandlerType.getTransactionDetailsRHandler);
    response = iRequestHandler.handleRequest(wsAttribute);

    if(wsAttribute.isSuccess())
    {
        beanresponse = (List<MyTransactionWSBean>) response.getBeanObject();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw handleException("getTransactionDetails", e);
}
return beanresponse;
}
```

the above code is calling my handler and handler is calling the persistence and returning the result back to this service.
here is my code for the persistence:

```
public class getTransactionDetailsPersistenceImpl extends BasePersistenceService {

protected final static Log LOG = LogFactory
        .getLog(getTransactionDetailsPersistenceImpl.class);

@Override
public WSAttribute createObject(WSAttribute wsAttribute) {

    LOG.info("Inside getTransactionDetailsPersistenceImpl");

    MyTransactionWSBean bean = null;
    String query = null;
    Session session = null;
    WSAttribute response = null;

    try
    {
        session = getHibernateSession();
    response = new WSAttribute();
    bean = (MyTransactionWSBean) wsAttribute.getBeanObject();
    long customerId = bean.getCustomerId();
    long sessionId = wsAttribute.getSessionID();

     query= "select id_txn,id_use_case,amnt_amount,str_text,id_payee,id_payer," +
            "(select str_identification from PBXMOB.customers_identifications " +
            "where ID_customer =" + customerId + " and ID_identification_type = 0) as payer_mobnum ," +
            "(select str_identification from PBXMOB.customers_identifications where " +
            "ID_customer = " + customerId + " and ID_identification_type = 8) as payer_sva " +
            "from pbxmon.mon_txns where id_payer = " + customerId;       

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     List<MyTransactionWSBean> resultList = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
     LOG.info("after executing query");
     if(resultList.size() > 0)
     {
         LOG.info("Inside resultList.size()");
         response.setSuccess(true);
         response.setBeanObject(resultList);
     } 

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOG.error("Error while Updating Customer Role", e);
    }
    return response;

}
```

Comment: You may be getting the 404 because the app failed to deploy due to an error on startup. What do the Tomcat logs show? Can you see any errors during startup?

Comment: no.. there are no errors..

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem???me too is having a similar one..